# MODX Revo Multilingual website not working

Tags: .htaccess, multilingual, modx, modx-revolution

I'am trying to set up multilingual website in MODX Revo following this article

http://designfromwithin.com/blog-webdesign-development/2012/01/12/modx-multilingual-setting-up-babel-and-have-a-website-with-multible-languages/

Index page works fine but when I switch to another language I have this message in Chrome:

**This webpage has a redirect loop**

Any ideas how to fix this?
Here's my .htaccess content, maybe something is wrong there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /modxr/

# Rewrite www.domain.com -> domain.com -- used with SEO Strict URLs plugin
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost/modxr [NC]
# RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/modxr/$1 [R=301,L]
# The Friendly URLs part
# redirect all requests to /ru/favicon.ico
# to /favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(lv|ru)/favicon.ico$ favicon.ico [L,QSA]

# redirect all requests to /ru/assets* to /assets*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(lv|ru)/assets(.*)$ assets$2 [L,QSA]

# redirect all other requests to  /ru/*
# to index.php and set the cultureKey parameter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(lv|ru)?/?(.*)$ index.php?cultureKey=$1&q=$2 [L,QSA]
```

P.S. I'm testing on WAMP local server

Answer (score 0):

To start with you have two lines in there you forgot to uncomment:

```
# Rewrite www.domain.com -> domain.com -- used with SEO Strict URLs plugin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost/modxr [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/modxr/$1 [R=301,L]
```

See if that doesn't stop the loop.

Comment: Then I have the same message and I can't even get to my admin panel

Comment: Hmm, since you are working on you localhost you could actually uncomment those lines completely. (all three)